# SoftLayer API Hardware : Fast Provision of BM Server PresetConfiguration OS

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Using the Fast Provision of BM Server REST API :

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/ordering-bare-metal-servers-using-softlayer-api

SoftLayer_Hardware/getCreateObjectOptions : In the response we will get fixed preset configuration,datacenter,operating system details,etc.,

When I provision using OS Reference code **ESXI_5.1_64**, I am getting the below mentioned error. In the request I have not mentioned networkComponents details and if i add **"networkComponents": [{ "maxSpeed": 100 }]**, details then also i am getting the below mentioned error message.

```
{
"error": "VMware ESXi 5.5 cannot be ordered with 100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

Also if i use some of the operating system reference codes i am getting the below mentioned error.

```
{
"error": "Unable to match an OS with reference code: XENSERVER_6.0_64"
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound"
}

 "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "XENSERVER_6.0_64"  "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "REDHAT_6_64"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. The exception:**

> { "error": "VMware ESXi 5.5 cannot be ordered with 100 Mbps Public &
>   Private Network Uplinks" "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public" }

Reason: The VMware OSes cannot be ordered with "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks" (e.g. "networkComponents": [{ "maxSpeed": 100 }]). VMware OSes must be ordered at least with "1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks". (e.g. "networkComponents": [{ "maxSpeed": 1000}]).

**2. The exception:**

> { "error": "Unable to match an OS with reference code:
>   XENSERVER_6.0_64" "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_NotFound" }

Probably you are trying to order a hourly server ("hourlyBillingFlag": true), this can be the reason of the exception, because this OS is only available for Monthly billing fee.

**Note:** If this is not the reason ("hourlyBillingFlag": true), you can attach the code that you are trying, in order to identify the issue and provide more feedback about it.

**How identify the type of billing for the items?**

Using **SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions** method, you will get a response like this:

```
38:  {
"itemPrice": {
"hourlyRecurringFee": ".024"
"recurringFee": "17"
"item": {
"description": "Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard Edition (64 bit)"
}-
}-
"template": {
"operatingSystemReferenceCode": "WIN_2012-STD-R2_64"
}-
}
```

"hourlyRecurringFee" means that the item is available per hour and "recurringFee" per month. The "XENSERVER_6.0_64" item is only available for month because it only has "recurringFee" property and not "hourlyRecurringFee"property.

Comment: 1 . After changing "networkComponents": [{ "maxSpeed": 1000}]) i am getting error message as : {
"error": "VMware ESXi 5.5 cannot be ordered with 1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}

Comment: 2. @mcruz Find the below mentioned payload for provision of REDHAT_6_64 in which i mentioned hourly flag as false but still i am getting the same error message as mentioned in my previous ticket. { "parameters": [ {"datacenter": {"name": "dal01"},"hostname": "vijvmware","domain": "csc.com","hourlyBillingFlag": "false", "fixedConfigurationPreset": {"keyName": "S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID"},
      "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "REDHAT_6_64"  }]}

Comment: try the following: {  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "datacenter":{  
            "name":"dal01"
         },
         "hostname":"vijvmware",
         "domain":"csc.com",
         "hourlyBillingFlag": false,
         "fixedConfigurationPreset":{  
            "keyName":"S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID"
         },
         "operatingSystemReferenceCode":"REDHAT_6_64"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: "hourlyBillingFlag": false value should be without ""

Comment: After changing "hourlyBillingFlag": "" it's working. Thanks @RuberC

Answer (score 0):

The OS ESXI_5.1_64 is not valid for your configured fixedConfigurationPreset (note based in your comments I assume you are using the S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID you did not copy your code :( ). For that preset the valid OS is ESXI_5.5_64. (VMware ESXi 5.5) So try this code:

```
{
    "parameters": [{
        "datacenter": {
            "name": "dal01"
        },
        "hostname": "vijvmware",
        "domain": "csc.com",
        "hourlyBillingFlag": false,
        "fixedConfigurationPreset": {
            "keyName": "S1270_8GB_2X1TBSATA_NORAID"
        },
        "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "ESXI_5.5_64",
        "networkComponents": [ 
         { 
             "maxSpeed": 10
         } 
       ]
    }]
}
```

Please keep in mind that the SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions returns all the options to create bare metal, but not all the convinations of options will work, that´s up to you to create the correct configuration for that you may see the UI (Softlayer´s Portal).

Comment: The above payload which you mentioned is not working and getting error message as : VMware ESXi 5.5 cannot be ordered with 1 Gbps Public & Private Network Uplinks. Also I agree with you that SoftLayer_Hardware::getCreateObjectOptions returns all the options to create bare metal server, but during provision  if it fails appropriate error message must be shown informing fixedConfigurationPreset is not valid or vice versa.

Comment: my bad change the "maxSpeed": 1000 to "maxSpeed": 10, that worked, please try that

Comment: That's great ! it's working. But still if API throws proper error messages during provision it's usefull. Thanks

Comment: yep you are right about the errors, it is frustrating some times

Comment: using Fast Provision :  "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "CUSTOS_1_64"  This is No OS it's not working and getting error message Unable to match an OS with reference code: CUSTOS_1_64. Let me know is there any changes are required in the payload. using the same payload which we discussed above.

Comment: Sorry man, No OS is not allowed for the configured "fixedConfigurationPreset" value. You can verify that in the Softlayer´s Portal https://manage.softlayer.com/Sales/orderBareMetalInstance/37276/64 you need to look for another one which allow it,

Comment: Using fast provision API, we can't order BM Server with NO OS ? If at least basic hardware model is allowed it's good right. we don't want to use the priceId (order,verify) api.

Comment: did you try this payload? { 
 "parameters":[ 
     { 
         "hostname": "rcdeletme", 
         "domain": "example.com", 
         "processorCoreAmount": 2, 
         "memoryCapacity": 2, 
         "hourlyBillingFlag": true, 
         "operatingSystemReferenceCode": "CUSTOS_1_64",
         "datacenter": { 
             "name": "dal01" 
         } 
     } 
 ] 
}